# Clearing previous line plots but retaining axes limits in Python

Tags: python

I have the following code in python

```
def animate(i):
    data_np = np.frombuffer(stream.read(CHUNK), dtype=np.int16)
    global ax
    ax.cla()
    ax.set_xlabel('time')
    ax.set_ylabel('audio amplitude')
    ax.set_xlim([0, CHUNK-1])
    ax.set_ylim([-9999, 9999])
    ax.set_title('AUDIO')
    ax.plot(x, data_np, lw=1)

    return ax


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  interval=20, blit=False)
```

I would not want to set the limits of the axes and title each time I enter this function. But i would also like to clear up the previous line plot. If i clear the previous plot using ax.cla() then that clears the entire axes setting, How can I retain the axes setting but just clear out the line plots.

Edit: Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pyaudio
import struct
import time

##########       Constants       #############################
# constants
CHUNK = 4096             # samples per frame
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16     # audio format (bytes per sample?)
CHANNELS = 1                 # single channel for microphone
RATE = 44100                 # samples per second
##########                       #############################


####################### Plot Config ##########################
# Setup the basic plot handles and configure plots

# print(plt.style.available)
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.cla()
ax.set_xlabel('time')
ax.set_ylabel('audio amplitude')
ax.set_xlim([0, CHUNK-1])
ax.set_ylim([-9999, 9999])
ax.set_title('AUDIO')
x = np.arange(0,  CHUNK, 1)
##########################             #########################


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(
    format=FORMAT,
    channels=CHANNELS,
    rate=RATE,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK
)
data_np = []
#line = ax.plot(x, data_np, lw=1)


def animate(i):
    global data_np
    data_np = np.frombuffer(stream.read(CHUNK), dtype=np.int16)
    global ax

    ax.plot(x, data_np, lw=1)


    return ax


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  interval=20, blit=False)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Hi @Anwarvic code is the question reproduces the scenario each time, you mean should i provide a code where data_np is generated more trivially?

Comment: yes, also how did you create `fig`?

Comment: have added the entire code to the question now, for reference

Comment: I've added my answer, hopefully this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jfaccioni, I was able to modify his answer a little bit to produce what the Original Poster wanted. All you need to do, is to modify the `animate` method to be like the following:

```
lines = [] # declare one more global variable
def animate(i):
    global data_np
    data_np = np.frombuffer(stream.read(CHUNK), dtype=np.int16)
    x = np.arange(0,  CHUNK, 1)

    global ax,lines   #include lines
    #add these two lines
    for line in lines:
        line.remove()

    lines = ax.plot(x, data_np, lw=1)
    return ax
```

Which produces the following graph:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works! One small question, in the call to funcAnimatiom when i set  blit=True instead of false I get the error "axessubplot object is not iterable" what could be the reason for this

Comment: The blit algorithm is used to determine which parts of the figure have been updated and your `animate` function needs to return an iterable of these things. I've never used it before. So, that's what I know

Answer (score 1):

`ax.plot` returns a list of all plotted lines ([Line2D](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html) instances, which are a subclass of [`Artist`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist)). You can simply call the `Artist`'s [`remove`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.remove.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.remove) method to attempt to remove the artist from the current figure, e.g.:

```
lines = ax.plot(x, data_np, lw=1)
for line in lines:
    line.remove()
```

Comment: I changed the code as follows: data_np = []
line = ax.plot(x, data_np, lw=1)


def animate(i):
    global data_np
    data_np = np.frombuffer(stream.read(CHUNK), dtype=np.int16)
    global ax

    line = ax.plot(x, data_np, lw=1)
    line.remove()

    return ax


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  interval=20, blit=True)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate() didnt work, error is x, y should have same first dimension

Comment: That's an entire separate issue. Apparently your `x` and `data_np` variables do not have the same size.

Comment: I have changed only this part of the code now, <ax.plot(x, data_np, lw=1)> (this works but previous lines are overlayed) to <line = ax.plot(x, data_np, lw=1)
    line.remove()>         with this I get the error,   " line.remove()
TypeError: remove() takes exactly one argument (0 given)"

Comment: Like I said, the return value of `ax.plot` is a *list* of `Line2D` instances (even if there's only one line). You need to iterate over the list like in my answer in order to call `line.remove()` on each `Line2D` instance, not on the list containing those instances itself.

Comment: Sure, I made this change, now there is no error message but an empty plot shows up with no data

Comment: Thanks for the help, it helped solve the issue, upvoted!